# TypeError: db.authenticate is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new with mongoDB thing and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. 
MongoDB have username and password.
Here is my code:

```js
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', {useUnifiedTopology: true}, (err, client) => {

  var db = client.db('Website');

  db.authenticate('username', 'password', function(findErr, result) {
    if (findErr) throw findErr;
    });

  db.collection('Games').findOne({}, function (findErr, result) {
    if (findErr) throw findErr;
    console.log(result.name);
    client.close();
  });
});
```

I tried to use it like this `db.authenticate('username', 'password');`

But all I get is `TypeError: db.authenticate is not a function` .

Comment: It looks like your code isn't checking if if 'err' is defined, so it may be hitting an issue when it tries to connect. Can you add a check to see if 'err' is null and print it out if not? This might explain what is happening.

Comment: I tried, is connected but I got `MongoError: command find requires authentication`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `db.authenticate` function. You can check the [doc](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Db.html).

If your mongo is protected by username/password that will be in your connection string(url):

The conenction string has this format:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]
```

Example from [Doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/):

```
mongodb://myDBReader:D1fficultP%40ssw0rd@mongodb0.example.com:27017/
```

Answer (score 0):

`db.authenticate` is a MongoDB shell function. It does not exist in drivers which is what applications (such as the one you are writing) use.

Both drivers and MongoDB shell use javascript, making this a common point of confusion.

In an application, provide credentials as part of the URI, or when instantiating the client, as indicated in the other answer.

Answer (score -1):

Verify what you type in:

module.exports = sequelize;

My error was = module.**export** = sequelize;

I forget use "s" in export.

After this is ok!

Try it

Comment: Please [edit] this post to augment it with the English version of what you provided in your other post on this page. Delete that other one.

Answer (score -1):

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize({

//*Type of databases and way//*

dialect: 'sqlite', 
storage:'./db/app.db'

});

//*Export to use with app.js*//

module.exports = sequelize;


//*After this create an constant in app.js that do representation the database*//
```

Comment: Please, answer in English.

Comment: Please delete this post and add an English version of it to your other post on this page. And please take the [tour] and read [answer] to find out why.

Comment: Sorry, but now I edited the text to english language.